# How do I mirror every inserts or updates from a table to another in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to mirror every inserts or updates from a table to another?

I have a database where entries are create and if they are no longer required, they will be delete. But I want to intercept every entry in this specific table before it is deleted.

Is there a MySQL in-built function to do that?

Comment: You can define a trigger which will be invoked whenever insert/update operation is performed to apply those operations on other table as well.

Comment: aah trigger, that's it. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't really about Ubuntu, is it ?

Comment: ubuntu is about everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [@Kulfy's comment](https://askubuntu.com/posts/comments/2108439), I can solve my problem with a MySQL trigger.

More information I've found here:

- [What are MySQL triggers and how to use them?](https://www.siteground.com/kb/mysql-triggers-use/#:%7E:text=The%20MySQL%20trigger%20is%20a,before%20or%20after%20the%20event)
- [MySQL :: MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 23.3.1 Trigger Syntax and Examples](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html)